# What does |operation| mean in Pseudo Code?

Tags: syntax, pseudocode

I have this line of Pseudo Code:

```
if |pos(point) - pos(point2)| <= K {

}
```

What does the pipe mean which I regard as the "or" operator.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like the mathematical sign for absolute value.

|x| = x if x >= 0

|x| = -x if x < 0

or in Java (most languages have something similar):

`Math.abs(x);`

Comment: ok, which means here: |pos(point) - pos(point2)| <= K if (pos(point) - pos(point2)) >= 0, right?

Answer (score 2):

In mathematical notation |something| stands for the magnitude of a value, so for example |5|=5 and |-5|=5.

In simpler terms it allows you to create an if statement in which only the size of a number is important not its direction, so;

```
if |pos(point) - pos(point2)| <= K {

}
```

Means "If the **size** of the difference between pos(point) and pos(point2) *ignoring sign* is greater than or equal to K then do.....